# I am getting this dkms error broadcom-sta, 6.30.223.271, 5.11.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom, dkms

this is my

```
dkms status
8812au, 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025, 5.11.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.11.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
broadcom-sta, 6.30.223.271, 5.11.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

I am new to Linux so I used multiple tutorials but nothing seems to work for my system.
I even ended up getting a TPU AC600 T2U Nano, and even that doesn't solve the issue as even that doesn't get installed

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1370600/edit) your question and add what version of Ubuntu you are using and also the output of `sudo lshw -C network` and what the actual problem is you are having.

Answer (score 1):

The following command should fix the diff error.

```
sudo dkms uninstall -m broadcom-sta -v 6.30.223.271 -k 5.11.0-37-generic && sudo dkms install -m broadcom-sta -v 6.30.223.271 -k 5.11.0-37-generic --force
```

and

```
sudo dkms uninstall -m bcmwl -v 6.30.223.271+bdcom -k 5.11.0-37-generic && sudo dkms install -m bcmwl -v 6.30.223.271+bdcom -k 5.11.0-37-generic --force
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The Wi-Fi still doesn't show up. It's now saying 'dkms status
8812au, 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025, 5.11.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 5.11.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
broadcom-sta, 6.30.223.271, 5.11.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed'

Comment: I'm sorry, I am terrible at posting here in the proper format.

Comment: @PragatNaik You fix the other module the same way as this one.  I'll update my answer here.  So what is the actual problem that you are having?  Are you getting no Wifi at all?  I have actually seen these drivers work even with the diff error, so I am actually lost as to what your actual problem is.